# remove duplicate from result in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have to combine values from two query and display as comma seperated and need to get distinct out of it. I tried to use join/union all or use distinct in each value but still i get duplicates if the values are common can someone please help with this. Below is my query and output

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 PV.serialnumber 
                 FROM ConsumerItemsTable PV 
                 WHERE PV.ItemID = 61) + ',' , '')  +
         ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + itemid   
                       FROM CustomerItems b  
                       WHERE Name = 'WillamRobbe'
                       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')  + ',' , ''))
```

Output of first query is 0991345

Output of second query is 0033874,0991345,8877425

- Expected output is 0033874,0991345,8877425
- Current output is 0991345,0033874,0991345,8877425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `union` and moving the outer `select` inside the `for xml` query using a derived table:

```
select stuff((
    select ',' + itemid
    from (
        select itemid
        from CustomerItems b  
        where Name = 'WillamRobbe'
        union 
        select top 1 serialnumber
        from ConsumerItemsTable pv 
        where pv.Itemid = 61
      ) s
    for xml path('') 
   ), 1, 1, '')
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UXIK17206

returns: `0033874,0991345,8877425`